# store/retrieve data from localstorage db using GWT phonegap

Tags: gwt, cordova, local-storage, mgwt

I'm newer to GWT,MGWT and gwt-phonegap .My task is to store or get the data from
local storage db of iPhone/Android device.Can any help me on this. I'm using 
Gwt-Phonegap in my application.if you provide me developed samples,I'll be very much 
thankful to you.

waiting for your valuable reply

Answer (score 1):

Local storage isn't a db

you can see examples [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Answer (score 1):

finally I became expert on LdbApi for GWT and MGWT to store date at client side.
I'm providing the link, so that It'll be useful to beginners like me.

[Local DB](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-localstorage-db/)

Comment: also we have were given with great support from html5 for the local Database. here is the link. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm